# Assign values to overlay in R?

Tags: r, r-raster

My problem is when assigning values to overlay.

```
  library(raster)
  beginCluster(10)
  r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
  r1 <- init(r, fun=runif)
  r2 <- init(r, fun=runif)
  s=stack(r1,r2,r2,r1,r2,r1)
  wi=c(3,5,7)


  fun1 = function(x) {overlay(x, fun=function(x) movingFun(x, fun=mean, n=3))}
  vm = clusterR(s, fun1, progress = "text")
```

no problem!

but when I assign `n` to `wi` it did not work

```
 for(i in 1:3) {
   fun1 = function(x) {overlay(x, fun=function(x) movingFun(x, fun=mean, n=wi[i]))}
   vm = clusterR(s, fun1, progress = "text")
 }
```

I got this error

> cannot use this formula, probably because it is not vectorized"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything inside the function has to be passed to it - it doesn't pick anything up from your environment because of the way the cluster operates.

So  pass `wi` and `i` to your function:

```
fun2 = function(x, wi, i) {
    overlay(x, 
     fun=function(x) movingFun(x, fun=mean, n=wi[i]))}
```

and list them as args in the call to `clusterR`:

```
for(i in 1:3){
 vm = clusterR(s, fun2, list(wi, i), progress = "text")
}
```